# How to generate React view from JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, api, reactjs

Starting out with React.js, I have an endpoint from my API backend that returns a JSON response. How do I access that JSON inside of a React component and loop through it creating copies of other elements:

Example:
...

```
class Books extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // have access to JSON here from API
  }

  render() {
   const books = jsonResponse.map((val) => {
    <img src={jsonResponse.imgSrc} />
    ...

   });
   return(
    {books}
   ); 
  }
```

So the var `books` should render based on the results from the JSON response

*Major Problem:* How to get the data inside of a Class Component, and possibly the best way to render from it.

Thanks

Comment: mapping through an array as you are showing is the best way to render.  as for the other question, what are you using to make your ajax request? if you havent chosen then [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) tends to be the most popular choice.  As a rule, it is best to make ajax calls in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method and then save the response to the component state.

Comment: @canaanseaton thanks, can you give links to resources where I can learn more on the `componentDidMount` lifecycle

Comment: @canaanseaton I know of axios too

Comment: [lifecycle method docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest (not necessarily the best) way is to fetch data in `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount` component lifecycle method.
You can choose from wide range of libraries able to fetch data. jQuery, fetch, axios to mention some.

You can find many tutorials by simple google search. E.g.: https://daveceddia.com/ajax-requests-in-react/

Comment: Thanks this is what I'm actually looking for